# nginx reverse proxy still works after deleting its config file

Tags: nginx

I had an config file named domain.tld in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled which configured a reverse proxy connection. the file looked like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;        server_name domain.tld
;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://111.111.111.111:80;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }




listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

It worked as a charm. Now I wanted to remove the config so I deleted the file and restarted nginx. But the config seems to be still working. My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is completly stock. What can I do to remove the config?

Answer (score 0):

1. nginx -t
2. restart or reload nginx as a service

Comment: 1. nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
2. I have restartet nginx, I even reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

When you change listen directive you have to restart(not just reload) nginx

Comment: I have restartet nginx, I even reinstalled it.